# Mock an extension method on the ClaimsPrincipal class for use within HttpContext.User

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, moq

Extensions aren't able to be mocked by frameworks such as Moq as they are static methods.

My ClaimsPrincipal class has an extension method that is used extensively within my app and cannot be changed. The extension method is called `GetUserSerial()`

I want to be able to somehow mock this extension method so that I can use it within my unit tests, as the extension method itself is used within various ASP.NET Core controllers and therefore I need to be able to mock the output of it to properly test the controllers.

I'm trying to mock the `ControllerContext` by doing the following:

```
private Mock<ControllerContext> GetMockControllerContext(Mock<ClaimsPrincipal> mockClaimsPrincipal)
        {
            if (mockClaimsPrincipal == null)
            {
                mockClaimsPrincipal = new Mock<ClaimsPrincipal>();
                mockClaimsPrincipal.Setup(x => x.GetSerialNo()).Returns("serial");
            }

            var contextMock = new Mock<HttpContext>();
            contextMock.SetupGet(ctx => ctx.User).Returns(mockClaimsPrincipal.Object);

            var controllerContextMock = new Mock<ControllerContext>();
            controllerContextMock.SetupGet(con => con.HttpContext).Returns(contextMock.Object);
            return controllerContextMock;
        }
```

```
public static string GetSerialNo(this ClaimsPrincipal claimsPrincipal)
        {
            return claimsPrincipal?.Claims?.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "SerialNo")?.Value;
        }
```

However this obviously produces the runtime error that tells me extension methods can't be mocked.

The main issue here is that the extension method is being used inside the controller itself and there's no way for me to alter the output of it.

Is there a way around this so that I can dictate the output of the `GetSerialNo` method and provide it within my `ControllerContext`?

Comment: As you are clearly aware. extension is not able to be mocked. **Show the extension method.** May be we can see a work around of what needs to be provided so that it can be invoked as expected.

Comment: @Nkosi I've added it to the question.

Comment: Ok no mock needed. Create a principal instance with the desired claim

Answer (score 3):

No mock needed. Create a principal instance with the desired claim

```
string expectedSerial = "serial";
var claims = new List<Claim> {
    new Claim("SerialNo", expectedSerial),
};
var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(claims));

//...
```

That way, when the extension is invoked, it will behave as expected.

If modifying an existing identity, then simply add the claim

```
//... principal already exists

string expectedSerial = "serial";
Claim claim = new Claim("SerialNo", expectedSerial);
(principal.Identity as ClaimsIdentity).AddClaim(claim);

//...
```

Comment: Just adding, because it was helpful for me, that if what you need to set is the role on the claim you can use `ClaimTypes.Role` as the type value for the claim (e.g. `new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, role)`).